# How can I get the last item of a table inside a for each statement on progress4GL

Tags: for-loop, progress-4gl

I've been trying to get the last item of a table after I iterated through it using a `for each` statement and the using `last-of` to get the last one, but it's getting all items instead of getting only the last one. This needs to be done inside a `for each` because I'm populating a website template(`.tpl`) with the data.

**Tables**:

> `table` has two items

**Here's my theoretical code**:

```
for each table no-lock 
    break by table.tab-code.

    if last-of (table.tab-code)
    then do:
       disp "last one".
    end.
    else do:
       disp "not the last one".
    end.
end.
```

**Output:**

```
last one

last one
```

Comment: Tom Bascom probably knows what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: Also, iIf you add "DESCENDING" to your break by, the first record the FOR EACH gets will be the last record in the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last-of will give you the last instance of each value of table.tab_code, so if you have three distinct values, it will test for the last instance of each of the distinct values.

What you are looking for is simply

```
if last(table.tab-code)
```

Comment: Oh, I see it now, I screwed it up, thank you for providing answer and explanation +1